# Why am I getting a "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." error?

Tags: python-2.7

I've been getting an error in this snippet of code that says my file path is incorrect. I know python likes to convert file paths to use double slashes (ie. \) however I am using a raw string variable. Does anyone understand why this is happening?

```
import os

comList = ['D:\\twidl\\data\\intel\\unlock\\unlock.bin\n', 'D:\\Kit025_02_TGF047K_7002\\BI\\TG-OEM\\Dell\\TGB047K_TGL051b7UB_1024.bin\n', 'D:\\twidl\\gui\\utils\\products.xml\n']

def remanTool():
    for string in comList:

        string1 = r"C:\Users\mgilmore\Desktop\FirmwareInstaller\WinPython-32bit-2.7.13.0Zero\python-2.7.13\python.exe"
        string2 = r"C:\Users\mgilmore\Desktop\FirmwareInstaller\TWIDL\PSHH_Reman.py"
        command = os.system(string1 + string2 + " -s " + comList[0] + " -f " + comList[1] + " -m "  +  comList[2] )
        print command
```

I expect the command to be run, however it keeps saying the file path is wrong.

Also, for reference, comList is basically just an array of directories.

The directories for some reason have been saved with endlines and double slashes. I've already tried using os.path.abspath().

Here is my error message:

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Surely you'd want a space between string1 + string2 ?

Comment: Maybe make some smaller steps before: First run the command from your console. If that works just hardcode the command and just do the os.system(...). If that works, start replacing one string into the hardcoded string, if that works, the next one.

Comment: Second question: Where is `comList` comming from? These \n at the end of the filename look error provoking! Also the loop variable 'string' is not used.

Comment: @Manuel comList is  an array that has firmware file directory strings in it. I have what has been stored written in the question as well.

Comment: How do you generate it? _Where_ is it coming from? Maybe there is the reason that you get these newlines

Comment: Can you please distill this down to a [mcve]? It would also make sure that you understand what actually causes the problem. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong guys, it was just an error in my text editor. All I had to do was restart the software.